# Accessing tcp port 8080 externally on macos mojave

Tags: macos, sockets, tcp

I am trying to access a listening tcp socket on my macbook from any external client on the same wi-fi lan.

This works for specific ports, eg. 8000, but not other ports, eg. 8080, 8081, 8082

How can I open up or access the 8080 tcp port externally?

## Working steps on port 8000

### Server

`$ nc -lv 8000`

### Client

```
$ nc -z 192.168.101.98 8000
Connection to 192.168.101.98 port 8000 [tcp/irdmi] succeeded!
```

## Non-working steps on port 8080

### Server

`$ nc -lv 8080`

### Client

`$ nc -z 192.168.101.98 8080`
(The command just hangs)

## Diagnostics

```
$ lsof -P -i TCP:8000
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nc      75782 ...    3u  IPv4 0x5be3e11e5a732339      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)

$ lsof -P -i TCP:8080
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nc      75952 ...    3u  IPv4 0x5be3e11e581e2fb9      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)

$ sudo pfctl -s all | grep Status
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
Status: Disabled                              Debug: Urgent
```

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (same behavior on 10.14 as well).

## Update

I changed nothing, everything suddenly works. I am very curious what made the difference. Will close the question, if everything keeps working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I had the **Endpoint Security VPN** client installed. This activates a firewall at all times blocking some ports. Even when not connecting to a vpn server.

By shutting down the client daemon, i can access all ports again.

### Steps to shutdown daemon

From: https://gist.github.com/phoob/671e65332c86682d5674

kill client and run commands to stop daemon:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.checkpoint.epc.service.plist
sudo kextunload /Library/Extensions/cpfw.kext
```